# Create logical columns based on token observations

Tags: python, awk

Here's an excerpt of a corpus:

```
w1, a1, c, f, s, w, q , p 
w2, p, z, l, c, t, w, k, e, d, a2 
w3, z, s, b, t, l
w4, a3, l, h, k, s, e, b
...
```

I am looking for the following output:

```
lemma, a1, a2, a3, b, c, d, e, f, h, k, l, p, q, s, t, w, z
w1,    T,   F, F,  F, T, F, F, T, F, F, F, T, T, T, F, F, F 
w2,    F,   T, F,  F, T, T, T, F, F, T, T, T, F, F, F, T, T
...
```

Normally, I'd make use of `collections.Counter` in python, but that words on dicts, and many of my lemma have the same value (are the same lemma). A different python implementation or even an awk  implementation would be helpful.

Comment: interesting, could you show people what you've already tried to make this a valid question?

Comment: Whar's a "lemma"?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) could work:

```py
data = '''w1, a1, c, f, s, w, q , p 
w2, p, z, l, c, t, w, k, e, d, a2 
w3, z, s, b, t, l
w4, a3, l, h, k, s, e, b'''

# Assuming "index" is first element in each row, splitting on comma
index = [row.split(',')[0] for row in data.split('\n')]
# For MultiLabelBinarizer, need an array-of-arrays/list-of-lists representation,
# so split each string in each row accordingly
data = [list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), row.split(',')[1:])) for row in data.split('\n')]

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

enc = MultiLabelBinarizer()
X = enc.fit_transform(data)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=X, columns=enc.classes_, index=index)
print(df)
    a1  a2  a3  b  c  d  e  f  h  k  l  p  q  s  t  w  z
w1   1   0   0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0
w2   0   1   0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1
w3   0   0   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1
w4   0   0   1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
```

If you want the vector to be represented as boolean, simply use:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=X.astype(bool), columns=enc.classes_, index=index)
print(df)
       a1     a2     a3      b      c      d      e      f      h      k      l      p      q      s      t      w      z
w1   True  False  False  False   True  False  False   True  False  False  False   True   True   True  False   True  False
w2  False   True  False  False   True   True   True  False  False   True   True   True  False  False   True   True   True
w3  False  False  False   True  False  False  False  False  False  False   True  False  False   True   True  False   True
w4  False  False   True   True  False  False   True  False   True   True   True  False  False   True  False  False  False
```